# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "http"

Tags: nginx, http

When I try to make code like it:

```
1. http {
2.    script
3.    server {
4.        ...
5.        location ...
6.    }
7. }
```

I get error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "http" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1
```

When code is like this:

```
1. server {
2.     ...
3.     location ...
4.     script
5. }
6. server {
7.     ...
8.     location ....
9.     script
10. }
```

...everything is stable. Does somebody know why I cannot use `http`?

I see in every example of good use can see the http, but I cannot use it good because of this error.

```
nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.10
nginx: TLS SNI support enabled
nginx: configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx/ --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6
```

Comment: solution is simply.. the main config file is not in
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
but is
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

:)

Answer (score 17):

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf is the main config file with the http {}, the files in conf.d are loaded *inside* that block, so the http is already there.

If you want to specify some config variable in the http block, put it in a conf.d file with no other tags wrapping it.